# Inspect button not available for Chrome on remote device in Chrome developer tools

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, chrome-debugging, android-debugging

**Problem**

So I got my phone showing up as a device in Remote Devices in Chrome Developer tools.

[image]

but

- the version of Chrome is missing
- the list of tabs in Chrome is missing which means
- the inspect button is missing

**More Information**

- I have adb server running on my laptop where I'm running the DevTools.
- When my co-worker hooked up his phone to my laptop, keeping everything else the same, there was no issue as described above. Worked normally.

Comment: Any kind of trust settings in security on your phone? Would be best if you can add details about the phone if it is specific to your phone only

Comment: @TarunLalwani what specific setting or section of settings do you want to see? Security under settings is a whole hierarchy of settings. Thanks.

Comment: Go to you developer options and see what WebView implementation it shows?

Comment: @TarunLalwani, it's hard-set to a single option: `Chrome Stable` and I can't change it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**There can be many things which could go wrong. Just check this things, Maybe can help you -**

- Update both chrome applications to the latest version (Android & Desktop)
- check if you can debug simple websites opened in chrome, if thats the case, there must be something wrong with your build.
- Confirm Turning on - *Developer options*, *USB Debugging*.

Comment: UBS Debugging has been on since the start. When that's turned off, the device won't show up at all under the devices list. I can debug simple / complex websites, and I can even debug Android apps with this laptop and browser, as long as I use my co-workers phone. Phone Chrome version is `73.0.3683.75`. Laptop Chrome Version is `75.0.3770.142`.

Comment: There must be something wrong with your device drivers then, have you tried to update, reinstall it by going into device manager

Answer (score 1):

It could be related to WebView implementation. Please go to Settings > Developer options > Change WebView implementation to Chrome.

Comment: On my `WebView Implementation`, I only have one choice and I can't change it. It's `Chrome Stable`. So, that setting has had that value for the duration.